# Guzzle 6 - Don't encode the URL

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

I'm currently using guzzle for my api requests however the URL is always being encoded. While I understand that this is normal the api I'm using doesn't work with special characters encoded.

For example:

`★ StatTrak™ Karambit | Case Hardened (Minimal Wear)`

is being encoded to - which causes the api to not work.

`%E2__%20StatTrak%E2_%A2%20Karambit%20%7C%20Case%20Hardened%20(Minimal%20Wear)`

please note that these are not being send as query strings.

The route for example is `api.test.com/price/★ StatTrak™ Karambit | Case Hardened (Minimal Wear)`

Here is my code:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri' => 'http://api.csgo.steamlytics.xyz/v1/'
]);
$request = new Request('GET', 'prices/'.$desc->market_hash_name.'?key=xxxx');
$response = $client->send($request);
```